# What are the differences between magento cloud extension and open source extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-community, magento-cloud, magento-commerce

I am searching about cloud extension and open-source extension in Magento. I didn't find any differences between them.

I checked the Magento Extension page, some Extensions have Commerce Cloud and Open Source Edition. For Example; [Extension Link](https://marketplace.magento.com/wyomind-ordereraser-meta.html?edition%5B%5D=open%20source%20(ce)&edition%5B%5D=commerce%20on%20cloud%20(ece))

[image]

If I want to develop an extension for Commerce Cloud, I don't know what I am doing. Please explain the **differences and similarities** Magento cloud extension and open-source extension.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am not sure what you mean by *'extension'*, but I am assuming you are referring to is the different Magento *'editions'*.

Code-wise, in a simplified way of answering your question, the Cloud edition has everything Commerce does (plus some additional tools), so you can directly compare Commerce vs Open Source just to have an idea of what the Cloud edition has as opposed to Open Source, so please check this https://magento.com/compare-open-source-and-magento-commerce.

Please check [one of my answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331305/magento-on-aws-vs-magento-cloud/331324#331324) on a question about the different Magento editions in the context of hosting to AWS. Although this is not precisely what you are asking for, I am sure it will help you understand the difference between the editions with regards to not only the code, but also the infrastructure.

---

***LE:***

Concerning installation of modules on Cloud, please check what the official documentation has to say on this:

> Magento installations hosted on Commerce Cloud require an extension to
> be installed in a Magento development environment where the
> integration can be tested and deployed to a staging environment before
> being pushed to production. To learn more, see Install, manage, and
> upgrade extensions in the [Magento Commerce Cloud Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/howtos/install-components.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the differences between Cloud Edition and open source. Let me explain a little more, what I want to ask. For example, I will develop a cargo tracking plugin. I developed this and ran it on open-source Magento. Does the same plugin work on Magento cloud? Is installation, deploying the same as open-source?

Comment: I edited my answer above, please check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I understood how can install modules to Magento Commerce Cloud. One more question, I developed a module for open-source. It is working great on my localhost. Is this module suitable for the cloud in terms of design and code? Does it work following these steps (Magento Cloud Module Install)?